# Joining my spreadsheet data to my geodatabase file is not including all matching records

Tags: arcmap, attribute-joins, relates

I have a map with roads, trails, and site gdb layers, and I have an Excel spreadsheet that I have imported with a list of the permitted companies for each of the designated roads and trails. I would like to join these so that I can click on any particular road or trail and identify which companies are permitted for the specific road or trail. Some roads and trails have multiple companies permitted, and those roads that do not have anyone permitted are not included in the spreadsheet (fine with having those be null values). When I attempt the join feature, all works except for the roads with multiple permits, the attributes table will only show the first matching record for that particular road or trail rather than all of the matching records regardless that I have selected "keep all matching records". In the join validation it states, Matching records may not appear in table due to join validation errors". I have tried the relates function, and once I click on "ok" after inputting all the related information, nothing is created, there is no output from running the relates. Attached is a screenshot of my spreadsheet layout and on the right is the validation I am getting. The next image you can see in the attributes table, that it is only populating the first entry for each road that has an entry.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I think  you'll need to do a query table instead of a join for 1:m (one to many) joins. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010848

Comment: What is relates function? Did you create relationship class?